# metaclass `__call__` method not called at instanciation

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I'm trying to understand metaclasses.

I already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/3156085) and I tried to use a custom `__call__` like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                               

class MetaTest(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("MetaTest.__call__ called.")
        return super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class Test:
    __metaclass__ = MetaTest


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```

I expected `Test.__class__.__call__` to be called at instanciation, and `Test.__class__` to be an instance of `MetaTest`, but it's not the case since I don't have an output when running this script.

So **why isn't `MetaTest.__call__` called at `Test` instanciation**?

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for metaclass usage in Python 3.x: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax. If you fix that, you will see the method get invoked as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed! I corrected it and `__class__.__call__` was called. Still have an error but that's an other question, this one is solved :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Python 2 syntax for metaclasses - but your shebang line and tags indicate you are running it on Python 3.

Just change your class declaration to declare the metaclass using Python' 3 way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                               

class MetaTest(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("MetaTest.__call__ called.")
        return super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class Test(metaclass=MetaTest):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```

Declaring a `__metaclass__`attribute on the class body has no effect in Python 3- but since it is just an attribute declaration, it raises no error either.